# Trigger link but don't change page content

Tags: java, javascript, redirect

Is it possible to trigger 2 links but only one to actually be loaded ? I need 'logout' not to load but somehow to be triggered in background (hidden), so he can do it's 'logout' function.

```
script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href='logout.html';
  window.location.href='index.html';
</script>
```

Comment: Can you not locate to 'logout.html' then on that page after the logout procedure relocate to 'index.html'?

Comment: No, I can't because the logout.html it's coming from the same domain but its a php software script which is totally different in design. That is why I must find a way to be trigger it but not shown.

Comment: Use ajax then. Only way a javascript script can initiate this sort of process. But having said that why not add a `header('location:index.html');` after the logout php script has complied?

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to achieve this. It is not necessary to load every url you want to execute. That is how modern day web pages are designed. Google more on ajax.

You can use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: redirecturl,
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
                // called when the call executes successfully
            },
            error: function (response) {
                // called when the call cant execute successfully
            }
        });
```

Comment: Some very simple example please ?

Comment: edited the answer with an example. You need to include jquery file in your page. You should try learning more about javascript.